# .length of object property accessed through getter and custom toString() is undefined

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

Here is an example JavaScript object:

```
var foo = {
    valueObj: {
        value: 'hello',
        toString: function() { return this.value }
    },
    get val() { 
        return this.valueObj; 
    }
}
```

I need to get the length of the string 'hello' stored in foo.valueObj.value. I need to access it with this exact syntax:

```
foo.val.length
```

foo.val should return valueObj, and it does. Calling foo.val.length then should invoke the custom toString method of valueObj, returning 'hello', and .length should return the length of that string. But it does not!

The following does work, proving that the toString() method does get invoked through the getter when a primitive value is expected:

```
foo.val + ' world'
//=>'hello world'
```

Why will .length not invoke the toString() method? How can I achieve what I need to here? Thank you!

Comment: `foo.val.toString().length` is the way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this.valueObj` doesn't have a `length` property. Asking for its `length` property does not cause an auto-conversion to a string (while concatenating a string does cause a cast to string).

If you do need to use that exact syntax (and cannot first perform a cast to a string), then the easy solution is to add a `length` getter to `valueObj`.

```
var foo = {
    valueObj: {
        value: 'hello',
        toString: function() { return this.value },
        get length() {
            return this.toString().length
        }
    },
    get val() { 
        return this.valueObj; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

No, accessing a property with the name `length` does not invoke the `.toString()` method. It accesses the `length` property.

If you want `.length` to be easily accessible, you can include it:

```
var foo = {
    valueObj: {
        value: 'hello',
        toString: function() { return this.value; },
        get length() { return this.value.length; }
    },
    get val() { 
        return this.valueObj; 
    }
};
```

Note that this could have unexpected consequences. Some libraries will assume that objects are "array-like" if they have a numeric `.length` property and try to iterate them using numeric indices (but your object doesn't have numeric indices). You may be better off actually using the `.toString()` method (or even just `.value`) rather than trying to get your object to pretend that it is a string.

Comment: Can anybody explain to me why you want to set these functions onto an object. JavaScript can do them natively? This gets the same result: `foo.val.value.length`?

Comment: @Mouser it's weird and that is preferable for sure, but OP might just be making a simple example to something more complex.

Comment: @Mouser I'm simply telling OP how he can do what he's trying to do, for the sake of argument. He may have a valid reason; it's hard to say.

Comment: @JLRishe, I wasn't trying to question the OP's coding, just wondering why someone would use this. Are there any benefits. Didn't knew you could do this until now.

Comment: @Mouser There would be a small benefit in being able to access `.length` directly (cleaner code) rather than having an extra property access to get to it. I don't think I would generally use objects like this, though.

Comment: @JLRishe, I follow you there. Thanks. However looks error prone to me if you need to add this to multiple objects.

Comment: @Mouser, yes this was a simplification of my code to show the basic concept. My application takes in user-submitted JavaScript. The user defines their own variables and can set properties on those variables. My task is to add the functionality that corresponds with the properties that they set. It's a little bit like making a domain-specific language.

Answer (score 1):

> Calling `foo.val.length` then should invoke the custom `toString` method
>   of `valueObj`

No. `foo.val` returns an object. And attempting to access the property `length` of that object won't call the `toString` method.

But you can use `expr + ''` to coerce to string, which will call `toString`:

```
(foo.val+'').length
```